# Python array values differ from defined function

Tags: python, arrays

I have defined and function and calling it to store the computed values in an array. However the  values in array are different than what they should be. I have plotted both the output of the function and stored array values. Can anyone help me resolve this issue. Here is the code and the output.

```
from numpy import linspace, exp
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

def gaussian(x, off, amp, cen, wid):
   return off+amp * exp(-(x-cen)**2 /wid**2)

PhaseArray = [0 for x in range (100)]

for x in range(100):
  PhaseArray[x] = gaussian(x, 0, 1000, 50, 15)

x = linspace(0,99,100)
fig = pl.figure()
pl.plot(PhaseArray, 'go-')
pl.plot(x, gaussian(x, 0, 1000, 50, 15), 'ro-')
pl.show()
```

The output plot looks like

[image]

Comment: `range` return integers, whereas `linspace` returns floats. E.g. try calling `gaussian(40, 0, 1000, 50, 15)` and `gaussian(40.0, 0, 1000, 50, 15)` and you'll see the difference. When you perform a division of integers the result gets truncated (for Python 2.7 and older).

Answer (score 2):

`linspace` provides a vector of float numbers that go to `gaussian` as a vector and are processed according to numpy operators over vectors. On the other hand, to fill `PhaseArray` you feed `gaussian` by integer `x` that is processed in a different way. It explains the difference.